# How to use to_dict and orient='records' in Polars that is being used in pandas?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-polars

I am not getting the same Output as of pandas in polars when i use `to_dict`.

**Example 1.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': [1, 2, 1,4,5],
    'column_2': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice','Tom', 'Tom'],
    'column_3': ['Alice1', 'Bob', 'Alice2','Tom', 'Tom']
})

test = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print('PANDAS',test)
```

with output

```
[{'column_1': 1, 'column_2': 'Alice', 'column_3': 'Alice1'}, {'column_1': 2, 'column_2': 'Bob', 'column_3': 'Bob'}, {'column_1': 1, 'column_2': 'Alice', 'column_3': 'Alice2'}, {'column_1': 4, 'column_2': 'Tom', 'column_3': 'Tom'}, {'column_1': 5, 'column_2': 'Tom', 'column_3': 'Tom'}]
```

**Example 2.**

```
dfPolars = pl.DataFrame({
    'column_1': [1, 2, 1,4,5],
    'column_2': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice','Tom', 'Tom'],
    'column_3': ['Alice1', 'Bob', 'Alice2','Tom', 'Tom']
})

testpolars = dfPolars.to_dict(as_series=False)
print('POLARS',testpolars)
```

with output

```
{'column_1': [1, 2, 1, 4, 5], 'column_2': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Tom', 'Tom'], 'column_3': ['Alice1', 'Bob', 'Alice2', 'Tom', 'Tom']}
```

Here, my first example is pandas and the output I got when I used `to_dict` with `orient='records'` as parameter. I expected to have the same output in polars.

Can someone help me out in a way that I can get in polars the same output as in pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To replicate the behaviour of pandas' `to_dict` with `orient="records"`, you can use [`pl.DataFrame.to_dicts`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_dicts.html) (notice the extra *s*).

```
df.to_dicts()
```

**Output.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
In [14]: [{col: value for col, value in zip(df.columns, row)} for row in df.iter_rows()]
Out[14]:
[{'column_1': 1, 'column_2': 'Alice', 'column_3': 'Alice1'},
 {'column_1': 2, 'column_2': 'Bob', 'column_3': 'Bob'},
 {'column_1': 1, 'column_2': 'Alice', 'column_3': 'Alice2'},
 {'column_1': 4, 'column_2': 'Tom', 'column_3': 'Tom'},
 {'column_1': 5, 'column_2': 'Tom', 'column_3': 'Tom'}]
```